# Remove text-decoration underline from :after content

Tags: css, hyperlink, pseudo-element, underline

**I don't want to use just `a {text-decoration:none;}` as I don't want to affect all links**

I have a div with `class="explore"` that has no content except `:after` which generates the content using css:

```
    content: "Explore";
    vertical-align: top;
    text-decoration: none;
```

I have then wrapped the div with `<a href="#">...</a>`

This give the text "example" an underline which I can't seem to remove; I've tried:

```
.explore a { text-decoration:none; }

.explore:after a { text-decoration:none; }

a .explore { text-decoration:none; }

a .explore:after { text-decoration:none; }
```

None of which seem to affect the text at all.

How can I remove the underline?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/17g9Ln28/1/)**

Comment: You should technically apply `text-decoration: none;` to the anchor tag. However since there's no parent selector in CSS (yet?) there's no way to target the `<a>` element by `.explore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply apply text-decoration for the link:

```
a{text-decoration:none;}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/17g9Ln28/2/)

Comment: I don't want to affect all links though

Comment: Then you can use parent div selector `#parent a{text-decoration:none;}`

Comment: Ahh so silly of me, I was adding to the child of the link not the parent!

Comment: @SaturnsEye this happens sometime. no worry.

Answer (score 35):

If you'll set `display: inline-block` to `::after` block, underline will disappear.

Comment: This did it to me! Thx.

Comment: Nice work like charm. Thank you so much for your answer. 1+

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My first question why do you want to use a `block` element inside an `inline` element which looks odd. Secondly you can make your markup just simple as below. Though you want to add block elements just add `display:block;` to your `<a>`

```
<a class="explore" href="#">explore</a>
```

**STYLE**

```
.explore{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/17g9Ln28/5/)**

Comment: Thank you, I've just reduced my code down by adding the class to the `a`

Comment: Pleasure helping you.

Answer (score -1):

You have to write one thing only
    a{
    text-decoration:none;
    }